Let $a, b, c$ be non-zero real roots of the equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. Then, no. of such triples $(a,b,c)$?
Let $a, b, c$ be non-zero real roots of the equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. Then, no. of such triples $(a,b,c)$ ?
My try:
Using vieta's relations:
$$a + b + c = -a \dots(1)$$
$$abc = -c \dots(2)$$
$$ab + bc + ca = b \dots(3)$$
From (1), (2) and (3), we get a biquadratic in terms of $a$ :
$$(a-1)(2a^3+2a^2-1) = 0$$
I ve seen only graphical methods of claiming that this cubic has a real root, but how to find out algaebrically ?

Part I: Derive the cubic.
For completeness, let's solve the system first:
$$
\begin{align}
a + b + c & = - a, \tag{1} \\
c a + a b + b c & = b, \tag{2} \\
a b c & = - c. \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
From equation $(1)$, we get
$$
b = - 2 a - c. \tag{4}
$$
From equation $(3)$, we get
$$
b = - \frac {1}{a}. \tag{5}
$$
Combining $(4)$ and $(5)$, we eliminate $b$:
$$
c = - 2 a + \frac {1}{a}. \tag{6}
$$
Plug equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ back into $(2)$ to see
$$
\left( - 2 {a}^{2} + 1 \right) - 1 + \Big( \, 2 - \frac {1}{{a}^{2}} \Big) = - \frac {1}{a}. \tag{7}
$$
Simplifying $(7)$, we get
$$
2 {a}^{2} - 2 - \frac {1}{a} + \frac {1}{{a}^{2}} = 0, \tag{8}
$$
or equivalently,
$$
{a}^{4} - {a}^{2} - \frac {1}{2} a + \frac {1}{2} = 0. \tag{9}
$$
This is a quartic equation. It should be easy to notice that
$$
{a}^{2} \left( {a}^{2} - 1 \right) - \frac {1}{2} \left( a - 1 \right) = 0, \tag{10}
$$
so $a = 1$ is a solution. If $a \neq 1$, then what remains is to solve the following cubic equation:
$$
{a}^{3} + {a}^{2} - \frac {1}{2} = 0. \tag{11}
$$

Part II: Show the cubic has only one real root.
Define
$$
\mathcal {f} \left( x \right) = {x}^{3} + {x}^{2} - \frac {1}{2}.
$$
Take its derivative:
$$
\mathcal {f}' \left( x \right) = 3 {x}^{2} + 2 x.
$$
It should be easy to see that
$$
\mathcal {f}' \left( x \right) = 0. \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad x \in \Big \{ 0, - \frac {2}{3} \Big \}.
$$
Since
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal {f} \left( 0 \right) & = - \frac {1}{2}, \\
\mathcal {f} \left( - \textstyle \frac {2}{3} \right) & = - \frac {8}{27} + \frac {4}{9} - \frac {1}{2} \\
& = - \frac {8}{27} - \frac {1}{18} \\
& = - \frac {19}{54},
\end{align}
$$
we know the graph would be something like this:


Part III: Find the unique real root.
We are now solving equation $(11)$:
$$
{a}^{3} + {a}^{2} - \frac {1}{2} = 0. \tag{11}
$$
Complete the cube:
$$
{\Big( a + \frac {1}{3} \Big)}^{3} - \frac {1}{3} a - \frac {29}{54} = 0. \tag{12}
$$
Rewrite the linear term:
$$
{\Big( a + \frac {1}{3} \Big)}^{3} - \frac {1}{3} \Big( a + \frac {1}{3} \Big) - \frac {23}{54} = 0. \tag{13}
$$
Recall the following cubic identity:
$$
{\left( u + v \right)}^{3} - 3 u v \left( u + v \right) - \left( {u}^{3} + {v}^{3} \right) = 0.
$$
Inspired by this, we let
$$
\begin{align}
u + v & = a + \frac {1}{3}, \tag{14} \\
u v & = \frac {1}{9}, \tag{15} \\
{u}^{3} + {v}^{3} & = \frac {23}{54}. \tag{16}
\end{align}
$$
Recall the following quadratic identity:
$$
\left( w - {u}^{3} \right) \left( w - {v}^{3} \right) = {w}^{2} - \left( {u}^{3} + {v}^{3} \right) w + {u}^{3} {v}^{3}.
$$
Inspired by this, we are solving
$$
{w}^{2} - \frac {23}{54} w + \frac {1}{729} = 0. \tag{17}
$$
Complete the square:
$$
\begin{align}
{\Big( w - \frac {23}{108} \Big)}^{2}
& = {\Big( \frac {23}{108} \Big)}^{2} - \frac {1}{729} \\
& = \frac {529 / 16 - 1}{729} \\
& = \frac {19}{432}. \tag{18}
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
w = \frac {23 \pm 3 \sqrt {57}}{108}. \tag{19}
$$
Finally, by $(14)$, we conclude
$$
\boxed {a = \frac {1}{3} \Bigg( \sqrt[3] {\frac {23 + 3 \sqrt {57}}{4}} + \sqrt[3] {\frac {23 - 3 \sqrt {57}}{4}} - 1 \Bigg).} \tag{20}
$$
Numerically, we have that $a \approx 0.56519 \; 77174$.

Very detailed work indeed.
